# Bind html form with XSL to dynamically filter xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

I have been looking for a solution and unable to find one.

I have an xml file and xsl file that is used to transform and display the xml file. I can sort and filter the xml document through the xsl file and it works fine.

```
<xsl:variable name="filval" select="'720p'" />
<xsl:for-each select="Movie_Prices/price[quality=$filval]">
```

I would like to have a html form with a select box and `onchange` event associated with it that when the user changes the value of the selectbox, the value is taken and replaces the `select="'720p'"` in the variable or directly into the Xpath to update the results.

```
<Movie_Prices>  
    <price id="1" status="use">         
        <quality>720p</quality>         
        <amount currency="LKR">20</amount>  
    </price>    
    <price id="2" status="void">        
        <quality>720p</quality>         
        <amount currency="LKR">30</amount>  
    </price>    
    <price id="3" status="use">         
        <quality>1080p</quality>        
        <amount currency="LKR">40</amount>  
    </price>    
    <price id="4" status="void">        
        <quality>1080p</quality>        
        <amount currency="LKR">50</amount>  
    </price>    
    <price id="5" status="use">         
        <quality>3D</quality>       
        <amount currency="LKR">80</amount>  
    </price>    <price id="6" status="void">        
        <quality>3D</quality>       
        <amount currency="LKR">120</amount>     
    </price> 
</Movie_Prices>
```

is this possible? any combination of xsl or javascript would be enough as long as the result works fine. Have searched alot and did not come up with a solution.

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: If you can manage to load the XSL dynamically (via JavaScript, perhaps) you might be able to use a global parameter and a top-level `<xsl:param name="filval">` to pass the values. I'm not sure if there is a way to do that in the browser, and if there is you would have to recompile your XSLT since variable and parameter binding is part of the static context. It would probably be more efficient to alter your XML via the JavaScript DOM API.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many options you have, you could simply use multiple stylesheets just holding the `filval`variable and import the rest using `xsl:include`:

**720p.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="filval" select="'720p'" />
    <xsl:include href="main.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do the same for **1080p.xsl** and **3d.xsl** and put all your template rules in **main.xsl** then select the corresponding file with the onchange of the select box with javascript.

Comment: Having done that, how would you bind the xml to the xsl?